# Existence of closed form function for every power series

Tags: power-series, closed-form, analytic-functions, formal-power-series

We know that corresponding to every analytic real valued function of a real variable there is a power series representation. I was just curious if the converse is true or not. The $a_n$ involved in the summation $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ can be any random function of $n$ which could supress all possibilities of a closed form representation. If the answer happens to be true, please provide for sufficient details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sum is just $\sum_{i=0}^n a_nx^n = (n+1)a_n x^n$. Do you mean
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of "radius of convergence"? What happens if you take $a_n = n^n$?

Comment: @gammatester Edited. Thanks

Comment: @MeesdeVries I think the radius of convergence would then be 0 but what are its implications?

Comment: There's no associated function, then. The series would converge only for $x = 0$. (You can prove this directly.)

Comment: For some coefficient sequences $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$ the radius of convergence is $0.$ But when the radius is positive, then the function is analytic in the interior of the region of convergence. But that doesn't mean it has what is usually called a closed form.

Answer (score 2):

If the power series has a positive radius of convergence $R$ then in the interval $(-R,R)$ it defines a real analytic function. That function is unlikely to have a closed form representation if by "closed form" you mean some rational expression involving polynomials and exponential/trigonometric functions.

In fact the term by term integral of your power series will define an analytic function that is even more unlikely to have a closed form expression: see

[How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: Small note: the guaranteed interval would be $(-R,R)$, whether the function can be extended to either bound depends on the function.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Indeed. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: In what cases will the function defined by power series in the interval $(-R,R)$ have a 'closed form' representation? Is there a criteria?

Comment: By the way, yes I exactly mean that when I say 'closed form' i.e. a combination of some known functions.